# Disable Java security and warning messages

Tags: java, security, executable-jar

I update Java 6 to Java 8u25 and now appear two messages:

**First message:** Do you want to run this application? Name: ----.jar

**Second message:** Warning - Unavailable Version of Java Requested:This application would like to use a version of Java (1.6) that is not intalled on your system.

These messages appear when a client run the java application (jnlp) and I would like to disable or hide their. The clients download the java application from a server.

I don't know if there are commands to disable their or with windows registry.

I know that there is a file called **deployment.properties** to add or remove parameters but I do not think it works in my case.

Comment: Did you update Java, or did IT push out an update to all your clients?

Comment: IT updated every clients to Java 8 but the server who had Java 6, has been  updated to Java 8 too.

Comment: Presumably if you want to run the application on Java SE 8, the application shouldn't be requesting version 6. Is there some reason why you can't change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can't.

Read Oracle's `deployment.security.level` property description and you'll see that for Java >= 1.7 **low security level has been removed** which means that even signed applications cannot escape security prompts:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html#properties

Since java 7, warnings can only be disabled/ignored after first instance by the user or by a ruleset set by the system administrator: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

(Starting with Java 8 update 20 medium security level has been removed too)

Of course you can force your clients to stick to 1.6 but that is **unsafe and unprofessional**, and you'll have to face potential warnings about Java version being obsolete anyway.

Comment: But the second message has relation with security?

Comment: Thanks. Are there any parameter to avoid that?

Comment: You can force your clients to stick to java 1.6 and forget about upgrading their JREs (then you won't need to change anything and they will see no warnings when launching your app) but that's unsafe and unprofessional.